# Access error when running alter table on the table that is being replicated

Tags: sql-server, database-replication, transactional-replication

I have the replication set up on the SQL Server from ServerName to ServerName2

- The replication folder is shared as `\\ServerName\repldata` and
- Replication snapshot-agent runs under the windows account `ServerName\repl-snapshot`, and
  the transactional log is under the account `ServerName\repl-log`.
  Both accounts have full acess to the replication folder, as well as the service account under which the `sqlserveragent` runs (`nt service\sqlserveragent`)

The replication itself works correctly, as far as I can tell.

Now, I need to alter the table that is the part of the replication, so
I ran the following `exec sp_register_custom_scripting 'CUSTOM_SCRIPT', '[dbo].[sp_storedProcedureSettingUpTheReplicationAndAddingArticles]', null, null`

And then I attempt to run the the alter table command, and .. get the error

> Msg 22048, Level 16, State 1, Line 0
> xp_create_subdir() returned error 5, 'Access is denied.'
> Msg 21330, Level 16, State 1,
> Procedure distribution.dbo.sp_MSreplcopyscriptfile, Line 44 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Cannot create a sub-directory under the snapshot folder (\ServerName\repldata\20240102152344170).
> Ensure that there is enough disk space available, and that the account under which the Snapshot Agent runs has permissions to create a sub-directory under the snapshot folder.
> Msg 3609, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

The very strange thing to me is that there is NO such folder/subfolder as `\repldata\20240102152344170`.

On the ServerName machine, the folder structure is

```
\repldata\unc\ServerName_publishDB_PublishDB\20240102154707
```

I am at loss now where to turn...

Comment: sounds like it needs write permissions to \repldata\unc\ServerName_publishDB_PublishDB so it can create 20240102152344170 and any relevant subfolders.

Comment: It has all the permissions ......